# Logged in user doesn't go to the home page (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

it can be simple, but i'm a beginner and i don't understand my mistake, i want to make my users that have already created an account go directly to home page ...

when I launch the debug, it tell :

*"Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Passerelle Widget*

*This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider*
*of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:*

- *The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.*

  *Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then*
  *other routes will not be able to access that provider.*
- *You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.*

  *Make sure that Passerelle is under your MultiProvider/Provider.*
  *This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately."*

here is my code, thank you for your help

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:dogos/HomePage.dart';
import 'package:dogos/pageAuth/inscription.dart';


class Utilisateur {
  String idUtil;

  Utilisateur({ this.idUtil });
}

class DonneesUtil {

  String email;
  String nomComplet;

  DonneesUtil({ this.email, this.nomComplet });
}

class StreamProviderAuth {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //creation d'un obj utilisateur provenant de la classe firebaseUser
  Utilisateur _utilisateurDeFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user){
    return user != null ? Utilisateur(idUtil: user.uid) : null;
  }

  //la difussion de l'auth de l'utilisateur

  Stream<Utilisateur> get utilisateur {
      return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_utilisateurDeFirebaseUser);
  }
}


class Passerelle extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PasserelleState createState() => _PasserelleState();
}

class _PasserelleState extends State<Passerelle> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final utilisateur = Provider.of<Utilisateur>(context);

    if (utilisateur == null) {
      return Inscription();
    } else {
      return HomePage();
    }
  }
}


class IntroductionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _IntroductionPageState createState() => _IntroductionPageState();
}

class _IntroductionPageState extends State<IntroductionPage> {

  
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser currentUser;

  getCurrentUser() async {
    currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    print("from get getCurrent user ${currentUser.email}");
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Passerelle()));
      });
    });
  }



  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      Expanded (
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      
      ),
      ),

    Container(
    child: Image.asset("assets/logo.jpg"),
    ),

    Expanded (
    child:Container(
      color: Color(0xff3b57fe),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      
      
      ),
    ),
  
      ],
    ),
    );
  }
}




class GetCurrentUserData {
  String idUtil;
  GetCurrentUserData({ this.idUtil });

  //la reference de la collection utilisateur
  final CollectionReference collectionUtil = Firestore.instance.collection('utilisateurs');

  DonneesUtil _donneesUtilDeSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    return DonneesUtil(
      nomComplet: snapshot['nomComplet'],
      email: snapshot['emailUtil'],
    );
  }

  //obtention doc util en Stream
Stream<DonneesUtil> get donneesUtil {
    return collectionUtil.document(idUtil).snapshots()
        .map(_donneesUtilDeSnapshot);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the current user in each page. and since you are returning`Passerelle` and as `MaterialPageRoute` then you should check for the current user inside this page.

Comment: and how can I do that ? what I have to add in code ?

Comment: Yes you have to add the code... await FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(); then check if user is not null then user is signed in so you can push any screen

Comment: where I have to add this code ? (I'm really a beginer and I don't understand all the code I use)

Comment: Try to add it above the if statement.. and in the if statement check for the value of user.

Comment: I replaced final utilisateur = Provider.of<Utilisateur>(context); by final utilisateur = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(); (utilisateur is the french world for user) It go directly to the HomePage even if there is no account created, maybe I don't understand what your telling to me, can you explain me exactly what I have to do ? Thank you so much